# Problem saving meta data

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm making my first WordPress plugin. I used an example to save text that an administrator enters when submitting a new post, but the meta data is not saving.

Can anyone help on that?

```
/**
 * Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens.
 */
function labishop_add_meta_box() {
        $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );
        foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
                add_meta_box(
                        'labishop_sectionid',
                        __( 'ADDING ITEM', 'labishop_textdomain' ),
                        'labishop_meta_box_callback',
                        $screen
                );
        }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'labishop_add_meta_box' );
/**
 * Prints the box content.
 *
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function labishop_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
        // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
        wp_nonce_field( 'labishop_save_meta_box_data', 'labishop_meta_box_nonce' );
        /*
         * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
         * from the database and use the value for the form.
         */
        $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ls_itemname', true );
        $value2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ls_price', true );
        echo '<label for="labishop_new_field">';
        _e( 'Enter your items here:', 'labishop_textdomain' );
        echo '</label> <br>';
        echo '<label for="labishop_itemname">';
        _e( 'Item NAME', 'labishop_textdomain' );
        echo '</label> ';
        echo '<input type="text" id="labishop_itemname" name="labishop_itemname" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="50" />';

        echo '<label for="labishop_price"><br>';
        _e( 'Item PRICE: (IRR/AMD/MYR)', 'labishop_textdomain' );
        echo '</label> ';
        echo '<input type="text" id="labishop_price" name="labishop_price" value="' . esc_attr( $value2 ) . '" size="50" />';
}
/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function labishop_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
        /*
         * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
         * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
         */
        // Check if our nonce is set.
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['labishop_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
                return;
        }
        // Verify that the nonce is valid.
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['labishop_meta_box_nonce'], 'labishop_save_meta_box_data' ) ) {
                return;
        }
        // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
                return;
        }
        // Check the user's permissions.
        if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
                if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                        return;
                }
        } else {
                if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                        return;
                }
        }
        /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

        // Make sure that it is set.
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['labishop_new_field'] ) ) {
                return;
        }
        // Sanitize user input.
        $ls_itemname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['labishop_itemname'] );
        $ls_price = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['labishop_price'] );
        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ls_itemname', $ls_itemname);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ls_price', $ls_price);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'labishop_save_meta_box_data' );
```

PASTEBIN: http://pastebin.com/bgtxLJML

Comment: Please try to narrow this down. Are your variable set correctly when you get to `update_post_meta()`? Does the code even execute that far at all?

Comment: s_ha_dum i tried that. all functions execute ( i tried putting an echo on them )
i checked the variables too...

Comment: Note there's a redirect after save, so put an `exit;` at the end of your debug code to actually see it!

Comment: TheDeadMedic beat me to it. You won't see output unless you kill the script during debugging.

Comment: Did that. the save function is not executing at all. Where is the problem? Cause i did `add_action( 'save_post', 'labishop_save_meta_box_data' );`

Comment: Put `echo 'Howdy'; die()` on the first line of the `labishop_save_meta_box_data()` function, and keep moving it down line by line until you see where things fail.

Comment: Thanks alot for that trick! trouble was with user permissions. IDK why, but it was there. Removed the `if()` checking about userperms. Thanks alot!